# What do the terms multiple point, singular point, ordinary point mean?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

On an algebraic curve, what do the terms "multiple point", "singular point", and "ordinary point" mean?

I have a pretty good grasp of the mathematics; my question is about the terminology.

For example, on the curve $y^2 = 1 - x^2$, the point $(x,y) = (1,0)$ has ramification 2.  Is this considered a "multiple point"?  I'm thinking it's not a "singular point" since it's locally Euclidean, but that doesn't seem to be the way [Bl33] defines the term.  [Bl33] says that a "singular point" is one where either the derivative or the discriminant vanishes. 
 Since the discriminant vanishes at $x=1$, I guess it's a "singular point".

[Bl33] goes on to distinguish between "points" (x coordinates) and "places" (x,y coordinates, with multiple places if there are multiple cycles), and an "ordinary place" is one where the $y$ expansion has no terms with negative exponents.  So, I guess $x=1$ is a "singular point", but $(x,y)=(1,0)$ is an "ordinary place".  But there's plenty of postings on stackexchange where "point" is used for what [Bl33] calls a "place".

Help!  Can somebody point me to some standard terminology?

[Bl33] Bliss, *Algebraic Functions*, 1933.  Reprinted by the American Mathematical Society, 2008.

Comment: First of all, I would warn you that some terminology has changed in the last 85 years. But to answer your question, the point $(1,0)$ is a ramification point of the projection map to the $x$-axis. It is, however, an ordinary point of the curve $x^2+y^2=1$. The point $(0,0)$ is a double point of $x^2-y^2=0$ and a triple point of $x^3-y^3=0$. On the other hand, $(0,0)$ is a singular point — a cusp — of $x^3-y^2=0$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin So have we dropped this whole concept of "place"?  In your double point and triple point examples, are you implying that these are not singular points?

Comment: Multiple points are particular kinds of singular points. If the curve is given by $f(x,y)=0$, then any point where $\nabla f(x,y) = (0,0)$ is a singular point. I have not heard the term "place" in recent years.

Comment: Places are still used, especially in number theory, but they are defined as equivalence classes of discrete valuations.  ([See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_theory#Places).)  There is an equivalence of categories between curves and their function fields ([see here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BXX)) and places of a function field correspond to points on the associated curve ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function_field#Valuations_and_places)).